# Symfony to implement a system of friends on a single table in relation of ManyToMany

Tags: php, sql, symfony, many-to-many

I have been here to ask you if you have knowledge about how to make a system of friends on one table?
I've already found a subject but it does not really explain how it went

I share what I did

in my users :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
 **/
private $friendsWithMe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $myFriends;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    $this->friendsWithMe = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->myFriends = new ArrayCollection();
    // your own logic
}
```

my question is how to display all my friends? even if I make a join how to make it show me a loop with all the friends?

thanks you for you helep !

Comment: Can you use the MakerBundle instead? https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle - This solves almost all problems with entities completely. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I have to do the relationship on her own is that?

Comment: Yeah, it should work if I recall correctly. That command should manage it all for you.